# A better way to obtain SQL data than I am currently using

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I need to retrieve data from an external SQL Server database and view it (not store it) in my ASP.NET MVC application. The only way I can connect to the server is by using a server name, port number and access to a SQL Server stored procedure that the server owners provide.

Currently the only way I know how to do this is by:

**a)** Writing a `.sql` script to retrieve the data. Note I can't see any of the SQL Server tables, I just have the name of the stored procedure and the criteria. I save the result as a `.txt` file

```
EXEC dbo.listData @Criteria = '<Portal><Data Name="Data" Format="Narrow" Interval="5m">

<Where>
<Column Name="Point" Project="XXX" Value="XXXX" Operator="LIKE"  />
<Column Name="Point" Project="YYY" Value="YYYY" Operator="LIKE"  />
</Where>
</Data>
</Portal>'

, @StartDateTime = '12/28/2020', 
  @EndDateTime = '12/29/2020'
```

**b)** creating a model class

```
public class Alarm_DataModel
{       
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public string Point { get; set; }
}
```

**c)** Creating a controller to put the data into the model to pass to the view

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string[] texts = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Test/test.txt"));
    texts = texts.Skip(2).ToArray();

    List<Alarm_DataModel> Alarm_Data = new List<Alarm_DataModel>();

    foreach (string row in texts)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
        {
            int x = row.Length;

            Alarm_Data.Add(new Alarm_DataModel
                    {
                        Project = row.Substring(0, 25),
                        Point = row.Substring(26, 60), 6

                    });
        }
    }

    ViewBag.Data = texts;
    return View(Alarm_Data);
}
```

My question may have been answered many times, but I have looked and can't find anything that I can interpret.

Is there a way that I can obtain the data using my controller without having to rely on the `.sql` script being ran and generating the `.txt` file?

With my limited access to the database, what is the best way to query using the provided stored procedure  and populating my model to pass to the view?

Comment: Everybody is "limited" to `a server name, port number` when accessing the sql-server? So how do you perform 1) - executing your `.sql` script file?

Comment: Take a look at the Dapper project, that will help you: https://www.learndapper.com/stored-procedures

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain myself well, what I mean when I say limited is When I log into the server I can't see the tables or even the schema of the data I am extracting. I can't actually see the stored procedure either, I just have the use of it. I can't edit the stored procedure or add another, I simply have access to use it. I will take a look at the Dapper project and see if it helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Frank Nielsen, your recommended code worked with just some minor edits with the criteria values. For some reason I needed to include them in the query for it to work.

Much appreciated, thanks

Here is the final code:

```
 public class AlarmDataController : Controller
{
    // GET: AlarmData
    private IEnumerable<Alarm_DataModel> GetAlarmList()
    {
        var sql = @"EXEC dbo.listData @Criteria = '<Portal><Data Name=""Data"" Format=""Narrow"" Interval=""5m"">
                    <Where>
                    <Column Name=""Point"" Project=""XX"" Value=""XXXX"" Operator=""LIKE""  />
                    <Column Name=""Point"" Project=""YY"" Value=""YYYY"" Operator=""LIKE""  />
                    </Where>
                    </Data>
                    </Portal>', @StartDateTime = '12/28/2020',@EndDateTime = '12/29/2020'";

        string connectionString = "Integrated Security=True;Data Source=XXXX;Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";


            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
               
                return connection.Query<Alarm_DataModel>(sql).ToList();
            }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var alarmList = GetAlarmList();

        return View(alarmList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Dapper the code would look something like this:

```
using Dapper;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

        private IEnumerable<Alarm_DataModel> GetAlarmList()
        {
            var sql = @"EXEC dbo.listData @Criteria = '<Portal><Data Name=""Data"" Format=""Narrow"" Interval=""5m"">
<Where>
<Column Name=""Point"" Project=""XXX"" Value=""XXXX"" Operator=""LIKE""  />
<Column Name=""Point"" Project=""YYY"" Value=""YYYY"" Operator=""LIKE""  />
</Where>
</Data>
</Portal>'";
            using( var connection = new SqlConnection("(connecting string here)") )
            {
                var values = new { StartDateTime = "2017.1.1", EndDateTime = "2017.12.31" };
                return connection.Query<Alarm_DataModel>(sql, values).ToList(); 
            }
        }
        
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var alarmList = GetAlarmList();

            ViewBag.Data = "texts";
            return View(alarmList);
        }
```

If the Stored Procedure can execute and reply with some data, everything is working with the credentials you are given. This is a normal production security setup.

That you also want to view tables, is a different concern and can be solved with different credentials or access to a another server.